# Travis CI Python build failing on osx - "2.7 not installed"

Tags: python, c++, travis-ci

I am trying to build a Python package with some wrapped C++ code on Max osx via Travis CI. This is my build config:

```
{
  "os": "osx",
  "env": "PYTHON=3.6 CPP=14 CLANG DEBUG=1",
  "sudo": false,
  "script": [
    "python setup.py install",
    "py.test"
  ],
  "install": [
    "if [ \"$TRAVIS_OS_NAME\" = \"osx\" ]; then\n    if [ \"$PY\" = \"3\" ]; then\n      brew update && brew upgrade python\n    else\n      curl -fsSL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | $PY_CMD - --user\n    fi\n  fi\nif [[ \"${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}\" == \"osx\" ]]; then\n    export CXX=clang++ CC=clang;\n    # manually install python on osx\n    brew update\n    brew install python3\n    brew reinstall gcc\n    virtualenv venv\n    source venv/bin/activate\n    pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade\nfi\n",
    "pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade",
    "python --version"
  ],
  "language": "python",
  "osx_image": "xcode9"
}
```

I get the following build error:

```
2.7 is not installed; attempting download
Downloading archive: https://s3.amazonaws.com/travis-python-archives/binaries/osx/10.12/x86_64/python-2.7.tar.bz2
$ curl -sSf -o python-2.7.tar.bz2 ${archive_url}
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
Unable to download 2.7 archive. The archive may not exist. Please consider a different version.
```

I'm not sure what to do about this.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, though I am using only python.

Comment: I believe that it's no longer happening, right? This is a Travis issue. You guys should talk to Travis support in order to get a solution for this.